# Warning Function 'getPositionValue' has a complexity of 7. Maximum allowed is 5

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, warnings

I am trying to get rid all of the warnings in my project, but i stumbled onto "warning  Function 'getPositionValue' has a complexity of 7. Maximum allowed is 5" and I am not sure how to solve it. It is a .js file.

This is the code:

```
export function getPositionValue(station) {
  const { latitude, longitude } = station;
  if (latitude && longitude) {
    return `${latitude}, ${longitude}`;
  }
  if (latitude && !longitude) {
    return `${latitude}, 0`;
  }
  if (!latitude && longitude) {
    return `0, ${longitude}`;
  }
  return `${0}, ${0}`;
}
```

Any idea how to solve this warning is welcome!

Comment: It's not clear why you need the `if` tests at all, if you're happy with the results having zeros.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **ESLint**, this errors refers to the **amount of paths that your code can pass until return** something. You can see the details of this rule at https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/complexity.

For solve the problem, you can use "if - else" [according to the docs](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/complexity#rule-details) instead of "if - if - if" sequence.

This method **could have a single return line** and return something like:

```
export function getPositionValue(station) {
  const { latitude, longitude } = station;

  return `${latitude ?? '0' }, ${longitude ?? '0'}`
}
```

This is a [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) that returns the value if exists, else returns 0.

also, you can [Change the maximum of complexity](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/complexity#options) in your ES configs (.eslintrc.cjs) for 7 (not recommended).

Hope I could help you.

Comment: This answer has been edited. Check the return line for more applicable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of using default values in destructuring so your function could look like:

```
export function getPositionValue(station) {
  const { latitude = 0, longitude = 0 } = station;
  return `${latitude}, ${longitude}`;
}
```

Comment: `getPositionValue({latitude: null})`

Comment: `${latitude || 0}, ${longitude || 0}` is more universal and preferable in this case

Comment: @VLAZ if "null" is a possible value in the input then one can change to:

```
export function getPositionValue(station) {
  const { latitude, longitude} = station;
  return `${latitude || 0}, ${longitude || 0}`;
}```